# cloning interfaces in Java

Tags: java

I have a problem in Java:

I have an interface:

```
public interface I extends Cloneable {

}
```

and an abstract class:

```
public abstract class AbstractClass {

    private I i;

    public I i() {
        return (I)(i).clone();
    }
}
```

but the usage of clone() yields the following error:

> The method clone() is undefined for
>   the type I

does anybody have any Idea how to get around this issue? the only fix I found is to add to I a new method: (I newI() ) that will clone I. is there a cleaner solution?

thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to override the `clone()` method to be public

```
public interface MyI extends Cloneable {
    public MyI clone();
}
```

Rather bizarrely, `Cloneable` does not actually contain the `clone()` method and `clone()` is `protected` on `Object`! It's been [discussed before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138769/why-is-the-clone-method-protected-in-java-lang-object) on SO

Comment: so as I understand, there is no cleaner solution than re-defining clone() (or newI as I called it) in my Interface, because Interfaces do not inherit from Object.

Comment: Yes - it's been my experience that a lot of people stay clear of `clone()` because it is so non-standard.

Answer (score 2):

What would happen if you changed:

```
return (I)(i).clone();
```

to

```
return ((I)i).clone();
```

?

Comment: no need. i is of type I. and the outer cast is needed because clone returns an Object type