# How to loop through a Map and clone each value?

Tags: java, for-loop, casting, hashtable, clone

I need to know how to for loop through a Hashtable, check for cloneability on each value, and clone if possible. This Hashtable has all String keys, but the values can be of any class. I have come across the following Hashmap example on another Stack Overflow page, but I need to do this with a Hashtable. More specifically, one without brackets. (Hashtable instead of `Hashtable<Type, Type>`.) I have also seen examples for looping through an ArrayList and cloning each element, but I need to do this with a hashtable. I have posted two pieces of code below: the first is the HashMap example I found and the second is my current proposal and the issues I'm running into.

The HashMap

```
public Map<String,C> deepCopy(Map<String, C> original) {
    Map<String, C> copy = new HashMap<String, C>(original.size());
    for(Map.Entry<String, C> entry : original.entries()) {
        copy.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().clone());
    }
}
```

My proposal

```
public class _HashtableCloningTest {
    public Hashtable deepClone(Hashtable original) {
        Hashtable newH = new Hashtable(original.size())
        Set<String> keys = original.keySet();
            for (String key : keys)
                if (original.get(key) instanceof Cloneable)
                    newH.put(key, original.get(key).clone());
        return newH;
    }
}
```

This code won't compile. The error says the clone method is on the object class, and the method on that class is protected. I need it to clone on the class of the current value, but since I as the programmer don't know that class, I don't know how to cast it to the proper class.

Any insight and help around this hurdle is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you cloning arbitrary objects at all? This is generally a code smell, IME.

Comment: It's the way my client wants it done. I realize there might be better ways but I need to know how to do it this way. I've been told it's possible, even if not the best solution.

Comment: The problem with your code is, that <code>Cloneable</code> is very hard to implement right, so for a lot of people it isn't the reliable way cloning you object. Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081858/about-java-cloneable To solve your problem you need to know what type of instances are put in this map and cast it properly.

Comment: `Cloneable` is basically a disaster in Java. Why does your client know enough about Java to care about `Cloneable`, but not enough to know how terrible `Cloneable` is?

Answer (score 1):

The `clone()` method is protected precisely to prevent you from cloning arbitrary objects, which is generally an indication that you are trying to do something strange.

It is somewhat inconvenient that `Cloneable` does not contain `clone()`. See the answer at [Why is the clone() method protected in java.lang.Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138769/why-is-the-clone-method-protected-in-java-lang-object) for a bit of a discussion on the matter.

See also the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/10083129/616460 for a few good pointers on issues with `clone()` in general.

In any case, if you *have* to do this...

One option may be to define an interface that marks objects as being able to be copied for your hash table and also provides `clone()`, e.g.:

```
public interface Copiable extends Cloneable {
    public Object clone ();
}
```

A second option is to create some interface that provides a method to make deep copies of an object, and have your classes implement that, e.g.:

```
public interface Copiable {
    public Copiable createDeepCopy ();
}
```

Still another option if you're desperate is to use reflection to invoke `clone()` on `Cloneable` objects. You may wish to think twice about what you are doing, though.