# How do i convince the compiler an Object is cloneable (java)?

Tags: java, cloneable

i want to clone a given object.

if i do this

```
public class Something{
    Object o; //set in the constructor
    public Something(Object o){
         this.o = o;}
    public Something clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException{
         Something temp = super.clone();
         if (o instanceof Cloneable) //important part
             temp.o = o.clone(); //important part
         else temp.o = o;
    }
}
```

this will not work becuase o.clone() is protected.

if i do this instead

```
         if (o instanceof Cloneable) //important part
             temp.o = ((Cloneable)o).clone(); //important part
```

it won't work either because Cloneable is an empty interface.

so how do i convince the compiler that you can clone o?

Comment: @immibis, I don't think your comment adds much value to be honest.

Comment: You must make your class implement `Cloneable` and implement the `clone` method.

Comment: From doc: "A class implements the Cloneable interface to indicate to the Object.clone() method that it is legal for that method to make a field-for-field copy of instances of that class."

Comment: Also, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138769/why-is-the-clone-method-protected-in-java-lang-object

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html

Comment: @aioobe Sure it does. It adds the knowledge that: you can't.

Comment: @immibis so it is actually impossible if `clone` has not been overriden?

Comment: @RishavKundu It's impossible to do sanely... but reflection allows you to do insane things, so you could try using that.

Answer (score 2):

You can't, when implementing clone() one must know what is cloning, must know the implementation class.

An alternative to cloning is to use copy-constructor, that has the same issue, you must know the class.

Some say do not use clone, others say define your own interface, eg: `Copyable` http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?CloneableDoesNotImplementClone

Answer (score 2):

Alternative would be to use serialization if it's possible to implement Serializable interface. Downside is the performance ofcourse.

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/SerializationUtils.html#clone(java.io.Serializable)

If you don't want to use apache commons you could do the same thing using ObjectOutputStream/ObjectInputStream.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with reflection

```
//We need reflection
import java.lang.reflect.*;
    //This class is the backbone of the feature
    public class MyCloneable implements Cloneable {

        //A constructor. For the sake of simplicity, the constructor is an empty constructor.
        public MyCloneable() {}

        //We implement the clone method. This returns a clone
        protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
            //We need the class of the object
            class c = this.getClass();
            //We get the empty constructor of the object
            Constructor constructor = c.getConstructor(new Class[]{});
            //newClone will be the cloned object
            Object newClone = constructor.newInstance(new Object[]{});
            //We get the array of fields
            Field[] fields = c.getDeclaredFields();
            //We iterate the fields to copy them. You might want to close these too, but for the sake of simplicity I did not tackle with this issue
            for (int fieldIndex = 0; fieldIndex < fields.length; fieldIndex++) {
                //We copy the field values of this into the clone
                fields[fieldIndex].set(newClone, fields[fieldIndex].get(this));
            }
            //newClone is ready and kicking
            return newClone;
        }

        //We need this method to be able to reach the clone method publicly
        public Object runClone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
            return this.clone();
        }

    }
```

This code is untested, any observation is welcome.

You need to use objects of classes which are inherited from MyCloneable.

Answer (score 0):

There is no general way to clone an object in Java. The type must provide a method to clone (which may be called `clone()` or something else; doesn't matter) in its public API, and there is no common supertype for such types in Java.

Answer (score -1):

The `java.lang.Cloneable` interface must be implemented by the class whose object clone we want to create. If we don't implement Cloneable interface, `clone()` method generates `CloneNotSupportedException`.

The `clone()` method is defined in the Object class. Syntax of the `clone()` method is as follows:

```
protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException
```

So your class should be as

```
public class Something implements Cloneable {

    private Object o; //set in the constructor

    public Something(Object o) {
        this.o = o;
    }

    @Override
    public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return super.clone();
    }

    public Object getObject() {
        return o;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Something s = new Something("try");
        System.out.println(s.getObject());
        try {
            Something s2 = (Something) s.clone();
            System.out.println(s2.getObject());
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Something.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The question was how to clone `o`.