# Overriding Clone() method in Java

Tags: java, interface, compiler-errors, clone, cloneable

I know I should implement the Cloneable interface and then override the clone() method of the Object class in Test, and this is not my problem . I just do not understand why compiler gives **"clone() has protected access in object"** error while the Test class is extending the Object!

```
public class Test extends Object{
public static void main(String[] args) throws CloneNotSupportedException  {
     Object o = new Object();
     o.clone(); }  }
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138769/why-is-the-clone-method-protected-in-java-lang-object

Answer (score 0):

The `clone` method is `protected` in `java.lang.Object`. The `protected` modifier specifies that the member can only be accessed within its own package (as with package-private) and, in addition, by a subclass of its class in another package.

ps. You will be able to call `super.clone()` from an overridden `clone` method of the `Test` class. Also make your `Test` class `extends Cloneable`.